# getting 404 while starting tomcat7 project

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat7

am trying to start tomcat 7, server is started successfully from command prompt. But when I am hitting my project url getting 404.

tomcat run command is

> catalina.bat run -config conf/mySchema.xml

FYI, I have configured host file with my project URL. could anyone help me to get it. thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at any of the Tomcat logs to see what is going wrong?

Comment: yes, I dont find any errors in log. just all the default webapps projects are deployed, like examples, ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

something wrong with the tomcat, I have downloaded the another tomcat and used it. The problem got solved.